# ksoap2 request wrong formed-

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl, ksoap2

This is my request:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Body>
<insertBeacons xmlns="http://tempuri.org/insertBeacons/">
<MAC_ADDRESS>gmg</MAC_ADDRESS>
<UUID>gmg</UUID>
<MAJOR>gmg</MAJOR>
<MINOR>gmg</MINOR>
<MEASURED_POWER>gmg</MEASURED_POWER>
<RSSI>rssi ejemplo</RSSI>
</insertBeacons>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

And i need send to service like that

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <insertBeacons xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <MAC_ADDRESS>string</MAC_ADDRESS>
      <UUID>string</UUID>
      <MAJOR>string</MAJOR>
      <MINOR>string</MINOR>
      <MEASURED_POWER>string</MEASURED_POWER>
      <RSSI>string</RSSI>
    </insertBeacons>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

can you see, in my request is with "v" and my service need "soap" word.

Anybody can helpme.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you asked this question, i faced the same problem when i started out with soap webservice. The key here is to avoid using soap libraries and go for the classes that java has provided to make the request and parse it i.e http,DOM parser or SAX parser. This is how you make your request without using ksoap or any other libraries.

Now on to the androiod code :

We will create a class named runTask which extends async task and use http to send the request body and get request response :

```
private class runTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            private String response;
            String string = "your string parameter"
            String SOAP_ACTION = "your soap action here";

            String stringUrl = "http://your_url_here";
            //if you experience a problem with url remove the '?wsdl' ending



            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {

                            //paste your request structure here as the String body.


                    String body = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">"+
                                    "<soap:Body>"+
                                    "<insertBeacons xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"+
                                    "<MAC_ADDRESS>"+string+"</MAC_ADDRESS>"+
                                    "<UUID>"+string+"</UUID>"+
                                    "<MAJOR>"+string+"</MAJOR>"+
                                    "<MINOR>"+string+"</MINOR>"+
                                    "<MEASURED_POWER>"+string+"</MEASURED_POWER>"+
                                    "<RSSI>"+string+"</RSSI>"+
                                    "</insertBeacons>"+
                                    "</soap:Body>"+
                                    "</soap:Envelope>";


                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);
                        conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
                        //you can pass all your request parameters here usong .setRequestProperty() method

                        //push the request to the server address

                        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                        wr.write(body);
                        wr.flush();

                        //get the server response

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


                            builder.append(line);
                            response = builder.toString();//this is the response, parse it in onPostExecute

                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {

                        try {

                            reader.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return response;
            }

            /**
             * @see AsyncTask#onPostExecute(Object)
             */
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



               try {

                  Toast.makeText(this,"Response "+ result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  //Go ahead and parse the response now

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Now in your onCreate just go ahead and execute this class using the following code

```
runTask task = new runTask();
task.execute();
```

You will get your response in your onPostExecute, format and parse it from here.
The main advantages of using this libraryless way is that it is flexible, you can format the request in any way the webservice requires as compared to the libraries which you only use the provided request formats. This solution works seamlessly in my code, feel free to ask for any further clarification.